# How can I check that Java JDBC code uses the right column names?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a test suite of end-to-end tests. They are supposed to catch typos in SQL statements, bad table or column names (anything where DB schema and Java code disagree), or missing DB permissions. I don't want to rely on data in the database (too complicated to set up); this is just a basic test.

```
import java.sql.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TypoTest {
    private Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db";
        String driverClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource";
        Class.forName(driverClassName).newInstance();
        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, "robert", "");
    }

    @Test
    public void runQuery() throws Exception {
        try (Connection connection = getConnection();
             PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT relname FROM pg_catalog.pg_class");
             ResultSet data = ps.executeQuery()) {
            while (data.next()) {
                data.getString("relname");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above test, it fails if I have a typo in the `SELECT` statement. (Good.) If I have a typo in the column name in `data.getString("typo here")`, that won't get caught if the table queried does not have data because then the loop is never entered. To keep the test (setup) simple, I don't want to insert data into my tables first.

I guess I could make the column names into constants and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up my code and get rid of the problem.

However, I am wondering if there is an easier way... I am lazy and don't want to edit all my queries. Is there a better way to unit-test my SQL?

I am using Postgres 9.5 and JDBC 4.

Comment: `SELECT a, b, c FROM some_table;` ***will*** fail if there is no column named `a` even if there are no rows in the table. The check for the column names happens long before the data is retrieved. There must be a different flaw in your test. Please show us the complete code for the test

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name you saved my sanity. I should have checked the code much better. You are right, the SELECT will fail. I had the column names in the SQL SELECT and in the code that converts the column data to Java objects. I had upgraded only the SQL SELECT, but not the converting code. That was why it did not fail without data. Again, my fault for not double checking the SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already [have the answer you seek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275921/how-can-i-check-that-java-jdbc-code-uses-the-right-column-names#comment58263791_35275921) but just for the sake of answering, you can try using [result-set-metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getMetaData%28%29) by using a `select * from table` and then checking the column names against your query (you'd have to parse the query string I guess...).

I believe it will work for empty tables as well but do note that I have not tested the empty table scenario.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but then it may actually be easier to have constants for the columns.

Comment: Yes. You could consider Enums.